# create POV-Ray image from DEM-file in grass

Tags: raster, grass-gis, dem, 3d, targa

I am working on `r.out.pov` Tool of grass 6.4 creating a POV-ray(beautiful 3D) image from an elevation raster.
[image]

You can see [this link](http://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/3D/) for more information about 3D analysis of `GRASS`.
[r.out.pov manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.out.pov.html)
Can anyone help me(step by step for windows) creating such an image of my DEM file? and some help about targa file (.tga).

Answer (score 1):

Please enjoy the related Wiki page which explains the required steps:

See http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/POV-Ray